# get name, size and timestamp of all files in dir

Tags: linux

I'm trying to get 3 attributes of all files(size, name and timestamp) present in all folders in main folder.

For example

```
MainFolder
   FolderA
          file1
          file2
          file3
   FolderB
          file4
          file5
          file6
```

Output should be

```
file1|size|timestamp
file2|size|timestamp
file3|size|timestamp
file4|size|timestamp
file5|size|timestamp
file6|size|timestamp
```

Is there any way I could do it using single command ?

Comment: You could use `find`'s `-printf` option, see e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html and search for the description of `-printf`

Comment: Which size? Size in blocks or size in bytes? Which timestamp? Time of creation, modification or access?

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f | xargs stat --format='%n,%s,%.19x' * | awk '{split($0,a,","); split(a[1],B,"/"); print B[length(B)],"|",a[2],"|",a[3]}'
```

Let me explain the 3 parts, first list all files in all subdirectories:

```
find . -type f
```

Then generate 3 columns with filename (will contain the full path), size in bytes and last access time (I trimmed to 19 characters), if you want another timestamp, like creation simply change the format of stat command as described [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html)

```
xargs stat --format='%n,%s,%.19x' *
```

Then as final step strip the path from the filename:

```
awk '{split($0,a,","); split(a[1],B,"/"); print B[length(B)],"|",a[2],"|",a[3]}'
```